# flutter video_player pacakge not working in ios devices(working in android)

Tags: video, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Flutter video player package not working in  IOS devices but videos are working in android devices.how to fix this?

I followed all the steps as mentioned in the video player package page.

Comment: Are you using a real iOS device or the Simulator?

> Warning: The video player is not functional on iOS simulators. An iOS device must be used during development/testing.

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -f mp4 -r 29.97 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -b:v 3800k -flags +loop -cmp chroma -b:v 4000k -maxrate 4300k -bufsize 4M -bt 256k -refs 1 -bf 3 -coder 1 -me_method umh -me_range 16 -subq 7 -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp8x8+partb8x8 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -level 30 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qcomp 0.6 -trellis 2 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -c:a aac -b:a 125k -ar 48000 -ac 2 outfile.mp4`

we converted the mp4 videos using above command then the video starts playing

Comment: Why dont you share exact procedure of your solution?